# Nested async function call causes lifetime issue

Tags: rust, future, lifetime

I feel like I am totally lost; what does "'1" mean in the error message?

```
error[E0597]: `o` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:32:19
   |
31 |     async fn foo6(&mut self, mut o: &'a mut Outer) {
   |                   --------- lifetime `'1` appears in the type of `self`
32 |         self.foo5(&mut o).await
   |         ----------^^^^^^-
   |         |         |
   |         |         borrowed value does not live long enough
   |         argument requires that `o` is borrowed for `'1`
33 |     }
   |     - `o` dropped here while still borrowed
```

What can I do to make `o` live long enough? I think I'm using futures 03.

```rust
use futures::future::BoxFuture;
use futures::FutureExt;
use futures::stream::FuturesOrdered;

struct Inner {}

impl Inner {
    async fn foo3(&mut self) -> Result<u32, ()> {
        Ok(8)
    }
}

// --- 1 
struct Outer {
    i: Inner,
}

impl Outer {
    fn foo4(&mut self) -> BoxFuture<'_, Result<u32, ()>> {
        self.i.foo3().boxed()
    }
}

/// --- 2
struct Outer2<'a> {
    futures_list: FuturesOrdered<BoxFuture<'a, Result<u32, ()>>>,
}


impl <'a> Outer2<'a> {
    async fn foo6(&mut self, mut o: &'a mut Outer) {
        self.foo5(&mut o).await
    }
    
    async fn foo5(&mut self, o: &'a mut Outer) {
        self.futures_list.push(o.foo4());
    }
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let mut o = Outer { i: Inner {} };
    
    let mut o2 = Outer2 { futures_list: FuturesOrdered::new() };
    o2.foo5(&mut o).await;
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=97b3d89e9c7a69480b17dc09e3bc42ca)

Comment: There is no "1" in the error message you've provided. What version of futures are you using?

Comment: @shepmaster Please see the playground link. I think it is futures 03

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `'1` represents the anonymous lifetime of the `self` parameter for function `foo5`.

Note that in `foo6`, `o` is already a mutable reference to `Outer`, so writing `&mut o` actually gives you a mutable reference to a mutable reference to `Outer` with one too many indirections. You can fix your code by removing the extra reference:

```
async fn foo6(&mut self, mut o: &'a mut Outer) {
    self.foo5(o).await
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=cb9aa5f09d331c8a5833ef9c0c279f86)

Comment: Thank you! Life saver!